# Libgdx | Scene2d | ImageButton setColor not working

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I have an ImageButton. The texture for it is basically a white square, with black text in the center. I want to be able to dynamically change the color of this button. The problem is that ImageButton.setColor does not do anything. I can call tint on the ImageButtonStyle which does work, but I want to be able to change the color later down the road if for instance the player clicks on the button. Thanks! Here is some code :

```java
ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle style_button_music = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
style_button_music.imageChecked = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite((Texture) Game.assetManager.get("button_music.png")));
style_button_music.imageUp = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite((Texture) Game.assetManager.get("button_music.png")));
style_button_music.imageDisabled = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite((Texture) Game.assetManager.get("button_music.png")));

button_music = new ImageButton(style_button_music);
button_music.setColor(new Color(22f/255f, 100f/255f, 255f/255f, 1f));

table.setFillParent(true);
table.setDebug(true);

table.top();
table.pad(100);

table.add(button_music).width(200).height(200);
stage.addActor(table);
```

Comment: try checking color value by button_music.getColor(); if it is changed then it must be sth with refreshing the view

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
button_music.getImage().setColor(Color color)
```

The `setColor()` on `ImageButton` is just inherited method from `Actor` but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It does do something...it tints the background drawable of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Actor color doesn't cascade down to children (except for the alpha component). Since the Image of an ImageButton is a child of the Button, the Image does not inherit the color of the Button.

However, the way in which you're currently using it, I think you could use a plain Button, and set the background image instead. That does get tinted.

```
style_button_music.checked = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(Game.assetManager.get("button_music.png")));
style_button_music.up = style_button_music.checked;
style_button_music.disabled = style_button_music.checked;
```

You should probably be using TextureRegionDrawable instead of SpriteDrawable. It's a much lighter-weight object, and it's rare to need the extra overhead of Sprites for buttons.

If you do need to use an actual ImageButton, and you're recoloring it dynamically, you could subclass ImageButton and use it's act method to transfer it's color to its child. That way you can use ColorActions with it.

```
@Override
public void act (float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    Color color = getColor();
    getImage().setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, 1f); //leave opaque, alpha transferred in draw()
}
```